# Office kitchen etiquette ( Teaspoons - hand wash or dishwasher )

Tags: professionalism, safety

After making a cup of tea/coffee in the office kitchen, I rinse the spoon under the tap, dry it on a tea-towel and replace it in the cutlery drawer. Most (*if not all*) co-workers put used teaspoons in the dishwasher, which leads to an empty teaspoon drawer by mid-afternoon.

Should I be doing this? I'd be happy using a teaspoon that I know was used, rinsed and dried, but perhaps others would not.

Comment: I've done the rinse-teaspoons-and-put-back-in-the-draw for years.  If you haven't actually eaten with it or put it in your mouth and you're rinsing with hot water then nobody is going to care.

Comment: I agree with JaneS - washing-up liquid is merely a degreasant and not necessary for a metal spoon that's only just come out of a hot cup of tea or coffee: rinse with hot water right after use, and then wipe clean and dry.

Comment: You are lucky. Most people throw their stuff in the kitchen sink. Even when the dish washer is two feet away, and there's a big sign "put things into the dishwasher".

Comment: Not sure how this is workplace specific? This topic could be discussed anywhere. What ties this question specifically to the workplace?

Comment: @Draken The issue of sanitation is non-workplace specific and should probably be asked elsewhere. But if it's sanitary (enough), this still involves how coworkers would respond or what they would prefer, which is very much on topic - in a home, for example, you can just come to an agreement with others, in a workplace you can't really do that.

Comment: @Dukeling Of course you can in a workplace. Do you not talk to your co-workers? If it's a larger corporation, there tends to be committees to discuss such trivial things. Smaller places, you can send an email around asking (If you're that concerned). This seems like a non issue to myself.

Comment: I would just go to the a cheap shop and buy 30 teaspoons for 3 pound and just use one at a time and put them in the dishwasher after use after some time there will be spoons the whole day

Comment: @Draken It doesn't seem appropriate to discuss something so minor with each of my coworkers or to ask a committee about it (it is minor, but that's not to say some people, like germaphobes probably, wouldn't be extremely bothered by it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I be doing this? I'd be happy using a teaspoon that I know was
>   used, rinsed and dried, but perhaps others would not.

Cleaning up after yourself is **always a good thing**.  The problem is that everyone has a different standard of cleanliness.

Some folks are even *more sensitive to this* and would not want to use a utensil that has been touched by anyone else ( other than to put it in the proper location) or just rinsed with water.

Since you cannot make everyone happy, or even know what is and isn't acceptable to others in this regard, I would simply put the *spoon in the dishwasher when you're done.*